# Partial specialization of function templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, partial-specialization

Does anyone know whether, in C++11, function templates can be partially specialized?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, they can't. The draft C++0x standard has a section (14.5.5) on class template partial specialisations, but no mention of function template partial specialisations.

Comment: It was my understanding that this is in C++0x.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes, I'm referring to the draft C++0x standard, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf

Comment: FYI:  The latest draft is now [N3126](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3126.pdf) [Warning:  Big PDF].  The answer isn't different in the latest draft.

Comment: The Feb 2011 draft again makes no mention of them: [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (10Mb)

Answer (score -1):

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562984/workarounds-for-no-rvalue-references-to-this-feature?noredirect=1#comment22690664_14562984); [they were proposed as core language issue #229](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#229) (from [n1295](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2001/n1295.asc)) but ultimately rejected (and quite rightly so, since overloading does the job).

Comment: I have to disagree with "quite rightly so".  Overloading does not always do the job since we can't have overloads that differ only on return type.  It would be nice if I could do something like the following, for example:

template <class T, class U> T& Foo() { ... }

template<class U> void Foo<void, U>() { ... }

Comment: I agree overloading is not sufficient.  Say I want to overload std::make_shared for a legacy C struct with custom create_* and destroy_* functions.  A partial specialization would be very useful in this case.

Comment: More disagreement to "quite rightly so": `enable_if`. If we could partially specialize functions, we could avoid clumsy hacks with tag helpers.