# C++ template specialization on functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, function-templates

I'm playing around with template specialization, and I've found an issue I can't seem to solve; this is my code:

```
template<int length, typename T>
void test(T* array)
{
    ...
    test<length-1>(array);
}

template<typename T>
void test<0>(T* array)
{
    return;
}
```

So what I'm trying to do, is to pass the length, of what's to be processed in the template.

The problem is, that the compilation of this, well outputs forever:

```
a.cpp:83:43: error: template-id 'test<0>' in declaration of primary template
a.cpp: In function 'void test(T*) [with int length= -0x000000081, T = int]':
a.cpp:77:9:   instantiated from 'void test(T*) [with int length= -0x000000080, T = int]'
a.cpp:77:9:   instantiated from 'void test(T*) [with int length= -0x00000007f, T = int]'
a.cpp:77:9:   [ skipping 151 instantiation contexts ]
a.cpp:77:9:   instantiated from 'void test(T*) [with int length= 28, T = int]'
a.cpp:77:9:   instantiated from 'void test(T*) [with int length= 29, T = int]'
...
a.cpp: In function 'void test(T*) [with int length= -0x000000082, T = int]':
a.cpp:77:9:   instantiated from 'void test(T*) [with int length= -0x000000081, T = int]'
a.cpp:77:9:   instantiated from 'void test(T*) [with int length= -0x000000080, T = int]'
```

Last two lines, is pretty much the same as the first ones.

To me it would seem, its not catching the specialization, hence:

```
a.cpp:83:43: error: template-id 'test<0>' in declaration of primary template
```

Am I correct?

And if I'm correct, I'm guessing it's the issue that partial template specialisation is not allowed for function templates, so what would be the solution then, making a struct, and using specialisation on that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Partial specialization of function templates is not allowed. Herb Sutter explains why in his article ["Why Not Specialize Function Templates?"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

To work around this limitation you need to use class templates instead. You can then write a regular function template that uses that class template.

That specific error you're getting is because you forgot the second parameter in your specialization. If you this instead:

```
template<int length, typename T>
void test(T* array)
{
    //...
    test<length-1,T>(array);
}


template<typename T>
void test<0,T>(T* array)
{
    return;
}
```

[GCC complains](http://www.ideone.com/Ty6zJ) with the following:

> error: function template partial specialization 'test<0, T>' is not allowed

Comment: So what would be my solution then, using a struct, and creating a wrapper function?

Comment: And why isn't it allowed? - just curious.

Comment: @Skeen To quote the article, "you can't partially specialize them -- pretty much just because the language says you can't".  With a footnote that it's being considered as a language feature in a future version of C++ (which would have been C++11 at the time).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a question from the link provided. In Example 2, how does the compiler decide whether (c) is a specialization of (a) or (b)?

Answer (score 9):

Functions cannot be partially specialized. To work around this, have your template function call a function in a class:

```
template<int length, typename T>
struct helper
{
    static void go(T* array)
    {
        ...
        helper<length-1, T>::go(array);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct helper<0, T>
{
    static void go(T* array)
    {
        ...
    }
};

template<int length, typename T>
void test(T* array)
{
    ...
    helper<length, T>::go(array);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Partial specialization of function templates [is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716799/partial-specialization-of-function-templates).

To work around that, you could make `test` a static member of a class template, and partially specialize the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround with a helper class. For illustrational purposes:

```
template<typename T, typename U> struct helper_t {
    static int foo () { return 0; }
};

template<typename T> struct helper_t<T,T> {
    static int foo () { return 1; }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
int frob () {
    return helper_t<T,U>::foo();
}
```