# Is this full template specialization, and is it allowed?

Tags: c++, templates

My original question was partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773302/specialization-of-templated-member-function-in-templated-class)

I still have to insist on one specific point. I try to specialize the following snippet with respect to U:

```
   template <class T, Location L>
    template <class U>
    Type Buffer<T, L>::getType(){
        return Type::INT;
    }
```

After reading some threads, I come to the following statemets:

- So there's absolutely no way to specialize with respect to U only, right?
- I can NOT specialize a member without specializing the class, no
  matter whether I specialize with respect to a class template
  parameter (T, L) or the function template parameter (U), right?

Experienced programmers may think that the question was already answered many times, but as a beginner in templates I could not confirm these statements absolutely certain.

Comment: See the following questions: [C++ template specialization on functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623375/c-template-specialization-on-functions) and [A workaround for partial specialization of function template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237126/a-workaround-for-partial-specialization-of-function-template).

Comment: I'm getting more and more confused, but in my eyes it's not a partial specialization of getType, but a full specialization. The member function will be specialized for all its template parameters (U).

Comment: It would be a full specialization if both template parameters of a class template and template parameters of a class template member were fixed.

Comment: Ah...I begin to understand the reason behind this, thank you!